# Enable action "Enter" on search box

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I'm just try to test my app, then i don't know how to make action "enter" on search text box after sending my search text to search box?

```
  it('Searching: search business', function() {
    element(by.id('search')).sendKeys('raw');
  });
```

am just sending the keyword 'raw' to the text box havig id 'search'